# ember/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects error for sorting property

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
import Controller from "@ember/controller";
import { computed } from "@ember/object";

export default Controller.extend({
  filter: "",
  filterTodos: computed("arrangedContent", "filter", function() {
    var filter = this.get("filter");
    var rx = new RegExp(filter, "gi");
    var todos = this.model;
    return todos.filter(function(todo) {
      return todo.get("title").match(rx) || todo.get("body").match(rx);
    });
  }),
  sortedProperties: ["date:asc"],
  sortedTodos: computed.sort("model", "sortedProperties")
});
```

14:3  error  Only string, number, symbol, boolean, null, undefined, and function are allowed as default properties  ember/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Comment: Hi Abbas, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you encounter eslint errors like this, you can do a google search for the name of the error, and you'll find the documentation that explains the reasons for the rules and how to fix them.  In your case: https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/no-function-prototype-extensions.md and  https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects.md.

If you have more specific questions about how to solve in your case, please give some more details in your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error, you are violating the eslint rule `ember/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects`.  Typically you can do a google search for the rule name and find the description of the rule and how to fix it.  Here's the doc for that rule: https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects.md

As you read in that document, you're not supposed to use arrays and objects as default properties.  I would read the Dockyard blogpost linked there to gain an understanding of why this is bad practice.

In your case, you are using an array for the value of `sortedProperties`.  According to the eslint rule documentation linked above, you would normally get around this by setting the initial value on `init`.  However, a sort property is a special case - and you can see the suggested approach by looking at the documentation for `computed.sort`: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/methods/sort?anchor=sort

As you can see, they suggest using [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), which will prevent the property from being changed.  So this should work:

`sortedProperties: Object.freeze(["date:asc"]),`

Comment: Please note that this is not an issue anymore if using native classes with ember as they provide class fields that are not shared between instances. You could read more about native classes in ember here: https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/02/11/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-1.html